# Does damage wake someone from the Sleep spell?

Tags: spells, wfrp-2e

The sleep spell puts a target into a slumber for 1d10 rounds causing them to be helpess. Does taking damage wake them? The spell does not say and nowhere in the corebook does it say...or at least that I can find.

As a GM I can see it both ways, more so because Warhammer has an old school fantasy feel to all their stuff and magic is both dangerous for the caster and those that are effected by the spell. On the other hand a balancing standpoint could be argued that they would wake up, however many spells and effects stun a target for x rounds which can be as deadly.

Comment: Hi Szadek, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. I've trimmed this question down to focus on the question itself since the background details aren't significant to it -- it looks like you've tried to do your research. Also, when you reach 20 rep, you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

### Its up to the GM

The *Sleep* spell does not clearly specify what happens.

> #### Sleep
>
> Casting Number: 6
> Casting Time: Half action
> Ingredient: A piece of down (+1)
>
> Description: Your touch causes one opponent to fall into a slumber
> for 1d10 rounds unless a successful Will Power Test is made.
> Sleeping characters are considered to be helpless. Sleep is a
> touch spell.

The only relevant information here is that the target is asleep (fall into a slumber) and helpless. *Slumber* is not really a condition well defined by the rules, and *Helpless* (pg 133) says:

> **Helpless**: The character cannot defend himself due to
> wounds, incapacitation, or some other circumstance. Attacks
> against the character automatically hit and inflict an extra
> 1d10 damage.

But how *deep* are they sleeping? I know I sleep like a rock sometimes, and probably even a sword stab wouldn't wake me up, but not everybody is like that, some people are really *light sleepers*.

I know that the spell **Winter's Long Slumber** (*Realms of Sorcery*, pg 141) puts the (willing) target to sleep for several months and the spell clearly states that normal damage has no effect on them, they must wake up on their own will. On the same book, the **Lucidity Tonic** also will put you to sleep *without interruptions* for several hours.

If we check the definition of the word [Slumber](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slumber), we see that it is most commonly associated with a *light* sleep (to my surprise, I always thought it was the opposite), so I personally would say that if the target takes *any* damage, they should wake up.

Keep in mind that helpless targets take an additional 1d10 damage, but that is more aimed towards being attacked by an enemy trying to kill you, not an ally trying to wake you up. So it's better to ignore that rule when the objective is not to kill the slumbering target.